# How to extends virtual type from di.xml

Tags: magento-2.1, extend, virtualtype

Is it possible to extends virtual type class declared in di.xml ? If yes how ?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you can't directly extend the virtual class in php file. But you can do with di.xml itself. Take this example, this may help you.

```
<virtualType name="SectionInvalidationConfigReader" type="Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="idAttributes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="/config/action" xsi:type="string">name</item>
            <item name="/config/action/section" xsi:type="string">name</item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="fileName" xsi:type="string">sections.xml</argument>
        <argument name="converter" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionConfigConverter</argument>
        <argument name="schemaLocator" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SchemaLocator</argument>
        <argument name="defaultScope" xsi:type="string">frontend</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="SectionInvalidationConfigData" type="Magento\Framework\Config\Data">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="reader" xsi:type="object">SectionInvalidationConfigReader</argument>
        <argument name="cacheId" xsi:type="string">sections_invalidation_config</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="sectionConfig" xsi:type="object">SectionInvalidationConfigData</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```